# How convert "for loop" to "recursive"?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I made a function follows

The "lists" below contains 12 list elements.

```
def calLen(lists):
    my_array = []
    count = 0
    for item0 in lists[0]:
        my_array.append(item0)
        for item1 in lists[1]:
            my_array.append(item1)
            for item2 in lists[2]:
                my_array.append(item2)
                for item3 in lists[3]:
                    my_array.append(item3)
                    for item4 in lists[4]:
                        my_array.append(item4)
                        for item5 in lists[5]:
                            my_array.append(item5)
                            for item6 in lists[6]:
                                my_array.append(item6)
                                for item7 in lists[7]:
                                    my_array.append(item7)
                                    for item8 in lists[8]:
                                        my_array.append(item8)
                                        for item9 in lists[9]:
                                            my_array.append(item9)
                                            for item10 in lists[10]:
                                                my_array.append(item10)
                                                for item11 in lists[11]:
                                                    my_array.append(item11)
                                                    my_set = set(my_array)
                                                    if len(my_set) > 7 :
                                                        count += 1
                                                    my_array.pop()
                                                my_array.pop()
                                            my_array.pop()
                                        my_array.pop()
                                    my_array.pop()
                                my_array.pop()
                            my_array.pop()
                        my_array.pop()
                    my_array.pop()
                my_array.pop()
            my_array.pop()
        my_array.pop()
    print(count)
    if count > 0 :
        return True
    else :
        return False

assert calLen([[0,1],[1],[2,3,4],[5],[1,4,7],[3,5],[6],[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[1,7],[2,5,7],[0,3,4]]) == True, "Error-1!"
assert calLen([[1,3],[2,7],[5],[6],[7],[2],[4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,7],[1,4,5],[3],[6]]) == False, "Error-2!"
```

I know... it looks stupid !

Luckily, "n (length of lists)" is fixed at 12 this time, but how can I change it to a recursive function if the value of n is different?

---

The problem what I want to solve.

given 12 lists, and each list has random numbers range 0 to 7, like `[0], [1,4,6], [6,7]`.

You have to get only one number from each list, and put them all to a set.

If you can make {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, then return True else False.

see `assert` example.

Comment: By writing a function that calls itself?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes. But anyway if you have better solution, I will thank you for sharing it :)

Comment: what is the logic ?? you want to add everything from all inner-lists to one single list ?? and then ??

Comment: I added the goal on the post.

Comment: @G.Anderson You can only take one element from each list. So, if you flatten the lists, you lose that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done recursively, but there's a better way. The standard library has a function to do that: `itertools.product` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
import itertools

def calLen(lists):
    count = 0
    for my_array in itertools.product(*lists):
        my_set = set(my_array)
        if len(my_set) > 7:
            count += 1
    print(count)
    if count > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Perhaps a simple example to make it more clear what itertools.product does:

```
>>> for combination in itertools.product([1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    print(combination)

    
(1, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(1, 'c')
(2, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(2, 'c')
```

Comment: @seongto This answer does not use recursion and is very inefficient. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed a problem that can best be solved using recursion. You have more control to make the correct checks in the code and only follow paths across the lists that possibly have the correct answer. Doing the 12 nested for loop are taking the product of 12 lists will not be an efficient solution.

Here is my solution:

```
def find_range(end, lists):
    def find_range_inner(index, se):
        # Return false if there are more numbers that have to be found
        # then there are lists to be searched for.
        if len(lists) - index - 2 < end - len(se):
            return False
        # Found all the numbers. 
        if len(se) == end + 1:
            return True
        # Check the options and return if any of them is True.
        # `any` will make sure it won't continue searching if
        # it already has found a True.
        return any(
            find_range_inner(index + 1, se | {el})
            for el in lists[index]
            if el not in se
        )
    return find_range_inner(0, set())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    li = [
        [0, 2],
        [0, 1],
        [3]
    ]
    end = 3
    print(find_range(end, li))
    li.append([1, 2])
    print(find_range(end, li))
```

It returns early if it found a solution, even if there are more lists. Also its efficiency is improved as `any` will directly stop iterating further if it finds 'any' True in the iteration.